# Using Tasker to block a specific number

Tags: tasker, call-screening

I was wondering if someone could help me with setting up a tasker profile to block an incoming call from a particular number. I've seen tutorials on how to block unknown callers or callers not in my contacts list, but I'd like to be able to specify a small group of numbers that would be blocked. Preferably I'd like to be able to just hang up on these callers, but sending to voicemail would be ok. I don't want the phone to ring or notify me at all of the incoming call. Thanks!

Comment: With Tasker you will always get a second or half second of ringing when blocking callers. What kind of phone do you have?

Comment: Ah, bummer. I have a Motorola Defy on Republic Wireless.

Comment: You can set `All calls to voicemail` option for a contact to redirect all incoming calls from that contact (even the contact has multiple phone numbers). The exact text for this feature varies from version to version, but the one I said is as in 4.1.2

Comment: Enhancing Narayanan's suggestion: create a single contact, and add all unwanted numbers to that. As you probably don't want to call/text that "contact", this would avoid "cluttering" your contact list -- and you don't need a specific Tasker task for that.

Answer (score 3):

Per this [link](http://tasker.wikidot.com/block-calls) you can create a profile that defaults to phone silence and changes the ringer to not silent when someone you want to take a call from or is not a person you blocked and then when someone you have blocked calls it will answer the call and hangup.

Here is a summary

1. Create new profile Allow Calls
2. Add context --> State --> Incoming Call

   - Specify who to allow calls from (ex. C:FAV (for favorites) or !)
   - "!" reverses logic (such as is not contact) and 0 can be used for anyone calling from a restricted or unknown number
3. Add Task --> Audio --> Ringer Volume

   - select ringer level (7 is highest)
4. Add Exit Task --> Audio --> Ringer Volume

   - select ringer level 0 (to silence the ringer once the phone call is done)
5. Create new profile Blocked calls
6. Add context --> State --> Incoming Call

   - Specify who to block (ex. !C:FAV (is not on favorites)  "0")
7. Add Task --> Phone --> Take Call
8. Add Task --> Phone --> End Call

This should allow your phone to ring when a favorite is calling and pickup and hang up on someone you wish not to talk to without you even knowing.

Comment: I tried to set up this mechanism on my phone but unfortunately the "Add Task --> Phone --> End Call" step will no longer work for me unless I run a specified ADB command sequence after each reboot, according to my phone. Is there an alternative? Rob